# PHP , How can I echo out a value before the calculation happens

Tags: php

Hello dear programmers, 
I have a small problem , have tried for hours to fix this problem , but it does not work. As You can see on the attached picture, i have a small php program , and the result of  $result is displayig correctly on line 20. But I want to display the same result in a previous div aswell( on line 3). I always get the error "$result is not defined" . Please help. 
Thanks a lot [here is the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9I7CS.png)

Comment: here https://s32.postimg.org/msc47sbpx/problem.png

Comment: Try is if(isset($result) && !empty($result) ){ echo $result; }

Comment: Post your code in your question, not as an image.

Comment: @  Mueyiwa Moses Ikomi , it does not work :( it displays nothing . I would post my code but it is quite long and confusing

Comment: <div>

<?php echo $result;
// I want to display $result HERE! but it doesn't work
?>

</div>


<div>

<?php

//some php calculations are made here
//...
//...
//...
//...
$result = $something +$something_else;
echo $result;
// $result is displaying correctly here , but not on the top on line 3

?>

</div>

Comment: Then only paste the relevant code, as you did with the image?

Answer (score 0):

Each time a page refreshes, the scripts starts from scrap and builds everything up meaning `$result` is not created yet. Work with sessions instead as it would allow for variable storage for next page request.

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['value'])){
  echo 'current value: ', $_SESSION['value'], '<br>';
}

$_SESSION['value'] += 1;
echo 'now value: ', $_SESSION['value'];
```